# How do I add zero padding to filenames that already have numbers in them?

Tags: rename, batch-rename

I used Sound Juicer to rip a CD of audio for a language learning book so that I could listen to them on my Android. However, Sound Juicer seems to only have the option of numbering files without leading zeros. Like this:

```
track_1.mp3
track_10.mp3
track_11.mp3
```

This leads to some confused ordering on my music player. So, I want to add some zeros to the name, so that they're ordered properly, like this:

```
track_01.mp3
track_02.mp3
track_03.mp3
```

How do I accomplish this? I tried using GPRename, but while it has the ability to add numbers, it doesn't seem to have any options for adding leading zeros.

Is there a better program or something I can do at the command line?

Comment: My answer on the duplicate should answer this pretty completely in a single command.

Comment: @Oli, although your answer works here too, the *question* actually is different, and other answers there do not necessarily work here, because of the preceding `track_` string. Mine needed editing anyway to make it work on this question.

Comment: @Oli, Jacob is correct. I had looked at similar solutions to the question you've linked to, but because of the particular naming scheme I was dealing with, it wasn't obvious that any file numbering solution would work. Marking this as duplicate is presuming a level of knowledge that precludes the purpose of asking questions.

Comment: The *question* is *exactly* the same, the input data is *slightly* different (which can either be ignored or easily adjusted for). When I'm back from holiday I'll spell out the flexibility of the `rename` method and expand the question for prefixed options.

Comment: I agree with Oli. `rename` in Ubuntu is the Perl-based one, and can do anything Perl can, and so is sufficiently powerful to handle such changes in input. `rename -n 'my ($first,$second)=split("_");$_=join("_", $first, sprintf("%02d",$second))' *` can do that, and I think simpler ways would exist in Perl. Since the question is closed, I can't add an answer.

Comment: also @muru, the fact that you can produce an answer that works on more than one question does not make the questions equal. See my reaction on meta http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11622/are-these-duplicates

Comment: @Oli, I think there may also be a conflict of interest here. If you weren't advocating for your own answer to take precedence, it would be easier to belive this was an objective determination.

Comment: @DaveMG [I've explained the technical reasoning behind the closure on Jacob's Meta Q](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11623/). That I have an answer on the master is just gravy.

Comment: @muru Off-topic to the duplication issue, that line would munch the extension. There is certainly a way similar to that which would work though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming that you just need to rename the files 1-9, since those are the ones that need padding. There are multiple ways of doing this.

You can execute the below command:

```
for n in $(seq 9); do mv track_$n.mp3 track_0$n.mp3; done;
```

This will rename tracks `track_1.mp3` - `track_9.mp3` to `track_01.mp3` - `track_09.mp3`.

---

To break it down, it looks like this:

```
for n in $(seq 9)
do
    mv track_$n.mp3 track_0$n.mp3
done
```

- `for n in $(seq 9)`: for every number in the output of the command `seq 9`, which is a command that just lists numbers 1 to 9, `do`,
- `mv track_$n.mp3 track_0$n.mp3`: this is the actual command that renames the files. It substitutes the value of `n` iterating through all numbers. So it does `mv track_1.mp3 track_01.mp3`, `mv track_2.mp3 track_02.mp3`, until that last number which is 9.

Comment: what should I do if not all images exist like .JPEG doesn't exist or 99.JPEG or 110.JPEG ?  `$ for n in $(seq 9); do mv $n.JPEG 0$n.JPEG; done;
mv: cannot stat ‘1.JPEG’: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

The script below wil rename files is given directory. It calculates the number of leading zeros needed, no matter the number of files (if >100, more zeros are needed), and renames the files automatically.

**To use it**

copy the script below into an empty file, in the headsection, set the sourcedirectory, the prefix ("track-" in this case) and the file extension of the files you want to rename. Save it as rename.py and run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py
```

The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import shutil
import os

sourcedir = "/path/to/sourcedir"
prefix = "track_"
extension = "mp3"

files = [(f, f[f.rfind("."):], f[:f.rfind(".")].replace(prefix, "")) for f in os.listdir(sourcedir) if f.endswith(extension)]
maxlen = len(max([f[2] for f in files], key = len))

for item in files:
    zeros = maxlen - len(item[2])
    shutil.move(sourcedir+"/"+item[0], sourcedir+"/"+prefix+str(zeros*"0"+item[2])+item[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are many ways of doing it.  You can, for instance:

- Separate the parts
- pad the part that has the number
- concatenate the individual part back to the new name

Put this into a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

item="track_1.mp3"

part1=`echo $item | awk -F_ '{print $1}'`
part2=`echo $item | awk -F_ '{print $2}'`
part2a=`echo $part2 | awk -F. '{print $1}'`
part2b=`echo $part2 | awk -F. '{print $2}'`
number=`printf "%02d" $part2a`
seperator="_"
newname="$part1$seperator$number.$part2b"
echo $newname
```

The loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for item in track_1.mp3 track_10.mp3 track_11.mp3
do
    part1=`echo $item | awk -F_ '{print $1}'`
    part2=`echo $item | awk -F_ '{print $2}'`
    part2a=`echo $part2 | awk -F. '{print $1}'`
    part2b=`echo $part2 | awk -F. '{print $2}'`
    number=`printf "%02d" $part2a`
    seperator="_"
    newname="$part1$seperator$number.$part2b"
    echo "Renaming $item -> $newname"
    mv $item $newname
done
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a script that will work like a **command**.

Make this file on the directory where you track file exist.

- Do like this

  ```
  touch change
  chmod +x change
  vim change
  ```
- In it write

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  n=0
  for m in {00 .. 99}
  do
     mv track_$n.mp3 track_$m
     n=`expr $n + 1``
  done
  ```

Comment: This would seem to move `0` to `00` then `1` to `00` then `2` to `00` and so forth. I don't think this is correct.

Comment: you can check the updated answer.

Comment: Fine, it should now produce the right outcome. But it should be obvious that you don't need to move anything higher than `9` as it will already have two digits. It should also be obvious that you only need to move `x` to `0x`, rather than having two iterators. Finally you have a `.mp3` missing. I think this answer is far from ideal.

Comment: the program is simple and will take care of all the files. And yes you are also right. i just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

GPRename will automatically insert a zero if you are renaming 10 or more files (two if you are renaming 100 or more, etc.) when using the numerical function. Just make sure `Zero auto-fill` is turned on in the `Options` menu.

Comment: This is useful to know. Although, GPRename, seems to not acknowledge existing numbers, so it seems to not fix this particular situation.