# convert all the png files in a folder to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert, png, avi

I have ~450 frames named 1...450. However, there are some missing frames for example frame 10, 30, and so on do not exists.

I want to create an AVI video in the same order as 1...450.png. How should I do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/624567/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-using-ffmpeg#comment845585_624573)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Option 1: Rename

1. First [rename](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503530/how-do-i-add-zero-padding-to-filenames-that-already-have-numbers-in-them) all of the inputs so they have zero-padding (`001.png`...`450.png`).
2. Then run `ffmpeg`:

   ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i %03d.png output.avi
   ```

   or

   ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png" output.avi
   ```

## Option 2: Sort

Use a more complicated command to sort the files and then pipe to `ffmpeg`:

```
cat $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png" | sort -V) | ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i - output.avi
```

Comment: if I use sort, I don't need to use zero-padding right?

Comment: @MonaJalal Yes. You can run `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.png" | sort -V` and it will show you the order that will be given to `ffmpeg`.